# add dynamic field near his parent field?

Tags: jquery

In my web page I am using **Add Dynamic Field Functionality**  by using jQuery.

I am adding a new div by clicking on an existing div:

```
<div class="divA">divA1 </div> 
<div class="divB" >DivB1 </div>
<div class="divC" />DivC1 </div>
```

By clicking on the parent `div` I am creating a new **dynamic div**

```
<div class="divA">DivA2 </div>
```

It is coming at the end of the all div's like that.

```
<div class="divA">divA1 </div> 
<div class="divB" >DivB1 </div>
<div class="divC" />DivC1 </div>
<div class="divA">DivA2 </div>
```

But I need it alongside the parent `div` like this:

```
<div class="divA">divA1 </div> 
<div class="divA">DivA2 </div> 
<div class="divB" >DivB1 </div>
<div class="divC" />DivC1 </div>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
    newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", text).attr("class", 'test0 ' + text);
    newTextBoxDiv.html('<div style=" width:150px; class="DivA" float: left"> </div>'); 
}

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#contents");
```

> **contents** is id of main div

Comment: and what jquery code you are using to doing this?

Comment: As Yograj says, we need to see your jQuery code to help you with this.

Comment: missing "" in you modify this as .attr("id", "+text") if your text is a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

***JS Code***

```
 $('.divA').on('click', function(){
      $(this).after('<div/>').next().attr('class', 'divA2').text('divA2');
 });
```

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mhn3q/11/***

Comment: @Kaps Hasija if modification needed please inform.

Comment: a modification added please check this.

Comment: that  is  class name is name of div  which  i  added daynamic

Comment: but your code doesn't contain any toggleClass() method yet. than how it will be applied to the created div?

Answer (score 1):

As your question stating, according to that.

You can try this

```
$("div").on("click", function(){
    var  _this = $(this);
    var className = this.className;
    _this.after($('<div />').addClass(className).html("New Html"));

});
```

and `<div class="divC" />DivC1 </div>`  should be as `<div class="divC">DivC1 </div>`

check this quick **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rwxv4/)**

Answer (score 0):

user $("your div selector").after("new div element");

http://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should give you exactly (I hope) what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/zjcHf/1/